# WPF Window properties code

Tags: discussion, support

I tried to post the XAML code where I thought that the `Window` properties were essential to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351404/have-image-size-to-the-window-but-not-the-window-to-the-image). Whenever I copy paste anything that has the `Window`, it never shows in the preview. I've got to format it as a code block. If I copy/paste this:

```
<Window x:Class="HDD_Drill_View.Windows.WndwMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="HDDC"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Name="wndwMain"
        Closing="WindowClosing"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowState="Normal"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

It doesn't show until formatted. Yet if I copy/paste:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Width="Auto"
               LastChildFill="False"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <DockPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Resources\background.png"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill"
                        TileMode="None" />
        </DockPanel.Background>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Height="Auto"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Label Style="{StaticResource HeaderLabel}"
                   Content="HDDC Reports"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Name="label1" />
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It shows just fine, and auto formats it as it should. Is there a particular reason for this? Can it be fixed to allow the autoformatting of copy/paste of that section of XAML?

Comment: Example please?

Comment: link? You probably didn't format as code so they appeared invisible. Formatting will cause them to appear

Comment: Added a link to my question. However, even if it wasn't formatted as code, the text still should have shown up as unformatted text, right? But you're correct, formatting it as code did make it appear.

Comment: no. Because XAML has angle brackets, the browser will think it's some HTML it doesn't know and not show it to you. I checked your link and I see the XAML in there so I'm confused.

Comment: @KateGregory: Copy/pasting works for anything but the Window tag. It treats that one differently.

Comment: chances are the XAML you were copying from was indented so the lines started with 4 spaces which is how we mark something as code. But the `<Window>` element was flush and so when you pasted it, it wasn't treated as code. My guess, anyway

Comment: @KateGregory I never really thought of that. I've never had any issue copy/pasting any code from any language, so I never thought that'd be a problem. But, it does kind of make sense.

Comment: @Mat: This wasn't a question about how to format my code blocks. I know how to do it. It's a question about why certain copy/pasted code blocks get automagically formatted, and another block did not. I've now got my answer, thanks to KateGregory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "auto formats as it should" capability. The editor does not notice whether what you type or paste is code or not. You can play with this a little to see it - for example, try editing my answer and you can see what I originally typed.

int i=3;
//I entered this as three lines
std::string s = "but they will all get squished together because I didn't indent them";

```
int j=2;
// this code is indented 4 spaces
std::string t = "and so it looks like code";
```

When you have a bunch of XAML and you paste it in, if it's from the middle of your file it's probably deeply indented. That means it comes out looking like code. That could lead you to think the editor is smarter than it is.

Then when you paste some XAML that is flush, it isn't treated as code, and unlike my C++ code above, the browser actually hides it because of the angle brackets.

**Solution:** always format code as code yourself. There is no auto format.